# Books or Info about Mac OS X under the hood

Tags: macos, resources

Can somebody point me in the direction of books, sites, articles, ... to learn everything about Mac OS X "under the hood"? In other words to learn more about the kernel, the system.

ps.: About Snow Leopard of course

Comment: for the books you can search in amazon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've read several articles by Amit Singh at http://kernelthread.com, and have always found them very interesting.

He's book is [Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321278542)

Comment: Is the book you've mentioned still relevant?
I ask this because it is from 2006 and maybe outdated?

Comment: @Geert VanLaethem: While the book is from the Tiger era much of it still holds true. Where the book is outdated the info should at least get you on the right track to find out what has changed.

Comment: I would think it's still relevant. I wonder if a second edition is planned.

Comment: It is the only book of that sort written specifically about OS X.

Comment: @Geert: The book is definitely still relevant.  I wondered the same thing until I got my hands on it... unless Apple changes the entire architecture and rewrite the kernel, this book will be useful for a long time to come.

Comment: calavera: can't wait for Mac OS XI

Answer (score 0):

Don't overlook http://developer.apple.com - there still is a free developer account option to get Xcode 3.  You can also buy Xcode 4 from the Mac App store for $5 and no developer account needed - the public documentation available through Xcode is impressive and comes from the web site. The free [Ingredients](http://fileability.net/ingredients/) browser also is superb for consuming and searching the Apple Documentation. You only need to pay for a developer account to get pre-release software and documentation so to learn about the current and past OS is free or nearly free.